# Append objects to a file using an ArrayList

Tags: java

Im trying to learn how to use an Array List to write objects to a file, however, the file keeps being overwritten and the data is not being kept when I restart the program:

```
System.out.println("Enter DVD title: ");
String title = inputScanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter main actor: ");
String actor = inputScanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter DVD's release year:  ");
String yearOfRelease = inputScanner.nextLine();
newDVD = new DVD(title, actor, yearOfRelease);
System.out.println("Entered DVD details: ");
DVDCollection.add(newDVD);
writeDVDs(DVDCollection);
break;
```

Above code takes input from the user and stores it in an ArrayList.

When I restart the program it seems to wipe everything.

```
static void writeDVDs(ArrayList<DVD> DVDs) throws Exception {
    try {
        Boolean append = true;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("DVDCollection.dat", append);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        for (int i = 0; i < DVDs.size(); i++){
            DVD theDVD = DVDs.get(i);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(theDVD);
            System.out.println("DVD successfully saved");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Cant write data to file");
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer again; and some feedback would be welcome ...

Comment: Just write the entire list. You don't need to iterate it. But you can't append to an object stream without taking special measures.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I didnt claim to be good at programming but this is def helping

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.

Your coding is missing the part of **closing** the `FileOutputStream` after writing to it. Depending on your context, this can leave things in a very inconsistent state.

And of course, with Java7, you should simply turn to [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to get your streams closed automatically! And hint: `System.out.println("Cant write data to file")` basically throws away all the **details** of the exact problem. You want to print the exception itself, too!

But beyond that, there is a **conceptual** problem. What your code is doing:

- filling an array list object
- opening a file for appending
- writing the objects into that file ... one by one

That works; but isn't exactly great. You see; in order to read those values back - how do you know how many entries are within your file?

I would rather suggest to *simply* write the complete list object itself. But of course, that would require to rework the overall solution - for example like:

- your method **first** reads the list currently stored in the file
- then you add the new objects to that list
- then you write that list to the file again (but in overwrite mode, not appending)

Long story short: you should probably step back and make up your mind what exactly your requirement is; and how to get there in clean way.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post, the reason for the project is to allow the user to create a list of their DVDs, store said list and edit the list. P.S. im a student just starting programming, i have less than 6 months experience

Comment: That isn't a problem. But when newbies ask questions it is typical that questions come back. It is thus not so great to drop a question here and walk away for hours...